# Script or software: Take a section of HTML from a page and use it in another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Bear with me, I'm not a programmer.

Is there a JavaScript or software or something that can take a chunk of HTML from a page that sits in one domain, and use it/parse it in another page that sits in a different domain?

Let me make a quick example:

On domain A - ***a.com*** is this HTML:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
  <ul>
  <p>Pargraph info...</p>
  <table>
    ...
  <table>
</div>
```

On domain B -- ***b.com*** I would like to use only the `<table>` from domain ***a.com***

Is this doable?

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I have done this, but in vb.net.

Comment: Ok... Do you have an example we can check or something?...

Comment: Sorry the code belongs to my employer not me. This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861/options-for-html-scraping

Comment: Seems doing this isn't easy after all. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is doable with cross-origin resource sharing. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing

The issue there is that you need to be able to configure the site you are requesting data from to accept the origin of the request. Basically not going to happen unless you own that server.

The other approach you could look into would be writing a program to pull the HTML from the page you want. But then you aren't using the HTML in your website, you are just accessing it in a program on your computer. This would be a good approach if you just want to pull the table down for yourself, rather than use it as part of another website.

Comment: Is there something out there already written that anyone can use to download/pull the HTML of the page? I am not a hard core programmer by any means. So, as long as there's an easy systematic way of pulling the HTML, this idea could work. Because with the copy of the page/HTML, I can call bring a specific section of the page in a specific container with jQuery's `load()` method. So, is there something already built? Thanks for the info.

Comment: Yes, the solution was to build a custom program to pull the HTML.